# Combining two html forms (one on top of JSP page, other inside jQuery tab)?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, jsp

I have two simple forms and I want to save data on both these forms on clicking a single submit inside the jQuery tab.

I have read that it's better to combine 2 forms than having single submit button for these forms. I am using Strut2 where these both go to the same action class. I am not getting how to combine two forms that are in two different location.

Please comment if you need the code.

Comment: submit how? AJAX or browser default?

Comment: normal submit button `<input type="submit" value="Save Note" id="saveNoteButton" />`

Comment: for details visit [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711443/submit-two-html-form-in-jsp-using-single-submit-button-tried-ajax-but-not-worki)

Comment: is AJAX OK? Fairly easy to serialize 2 forms into one submit object. Default submit requires combining into one form ( also not very diffciult). Problem with calling `submit()` for two forms without AJAX is second submit will be blocked by redirect of first form, so only first form will get submitted

Comment: also if want more help... put both forms live html into jsfiddle.net demo

Comment: I dont know much if jsfiddle. still i tried to do what ever I can. @charlietfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send data via AJAX can do following, just adjust ID's of forms accordingly:

```
$('#saveNoteButton').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();/* prevent browser default submit*/
    var inputs=$('#form1,#form2').find(':input').not(this);
    var form_data={};
    inputs.each(function(){
        var $this=$(this)
        if( $this.is(':radio') && !this.checked){
            return;
        }
        form_data[this.name]=$this.val();
    });

    /* now send via AJAX*/
  $.post('/path/To/Server/',  form_data, function(response){  
        // do something with server response here
    });/* if return json add datatype argument, see docs*/


});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/HnyYe/1

**UPdated** - tweak for only radios that are checked